# Add a value to the multiIndex if it does not exist pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a big problem.

I have a multiIndex dataframe like this

```
                                time_total_x_x  time_total_y    perc_time   time_total_x_y  perc_sec_time
sector  radiotap.mcs.index                  
2       1.0000000000            0.1079160312    0.1505082861    0.7170105646    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        2.0000000000            0.0101262961    0.1505082861    0.0672806552    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        3.0000000000            0.0074302504    0.1505082861    0.0493677164    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        4.0000000000            0.0057511342    0.1505082861    0.0382114125    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        6.0000000000            0.0053130805    0.1505082861    0.0353009170    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        7.0000000000            0.0056565361    0.1505082861    0.0375828883    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        8.0000000000            0.0083149576    0.1505082861    0.0552458459    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
3       1.0000000000            0.0326363429    0.0553721351    0.5894001165    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        3.0000000000            0.0037409247    0.0553721351    0.0675596971    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        6.0000000000            0.0013867221    0.0553721351    0.0250436808    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        8.0000000000            0.0097070545    0.0553721351    0.1753057659    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
```

and I need to add values to the index `radiotap.mcs.index` if the value does not exist, and fill the last two columns with the same value for the same index `sector` (but this is not important).

It should look like this

```
                                time_total_x_x  time_total_y    perc_time       time_total_x_y  perc_sec_time
sector  radiotap.mcs.index                  
2       0.0000000000            0               0               0               18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        1.0000000000            0.1079160312    0.1505082861    0.7170105646    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        2.0000000000            0.0101262961    0.1505082861    0.0672806552    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        3.0000000000            0.0074302504    0.1505082861    0.0493677164    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        5.0000000000            0               0               0               18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        4.0000000000            0.0057511342    0.1505082861    0.0382114125    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        6.0000000000            0.0053130805    0.1505082861    0.0353009170    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        7.0000000000            0.0056565361    0.1505082861    0.0375828883    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
        8.0000000000            0.0083149576    0.1505082861    0.0552458459    18.0297726012   0.0083477640
3       0.0000000000            0               0               0               18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        1.0000000000            0.0326363429    0.0553721351    0.5894001165    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        2.0000000000            0               0               0               18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        3.0000000000            0.0037409247    0.0553721351    0.0675596971    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        4.0000000000            0               0               0               18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        5.0000000000            0               0               0               18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        6.0000000000            0.0013867221    0.0553721351    0.0250436808    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        7.0000000000            0               0               0               18.0297726012   0.0030711499
        8.0000000000            0.0097070545    0.0553721351    0.1753057659    18.0297726012   0.0030711499
```

Can anybody help me? I really need A LOT of that.

Answer (score 1):

Create product of index using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` and then `reindex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"sector":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                   "idx":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,3,6,8],
                   "values":range(12)})

m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["sector"].unique(),df["idx"].unique()],names=["sector","idx"])

print (df.set_index(["sector","idx"]).reindex(m, fill_value=0))

            values
sector idx        
2      1         0
       2         1
       3         2
       4         3
       5         4
       6         5
       7         6
       8         7
3      1         8
       2         0
       3         9
       4         0
       5         0
       6        10
       7         0
       8        11
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` to create the missing rows and join the original data frame. Then, replace NA with 0 by filling in the holes with `fillna(method='bfill')`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
sector radiotap.mcs.index time_total_x_x time_total_y perc_time time_total_x_y perc_sec_time
2 1.0000000000 0.1079160312 0.1505082861 0.7170105646 18.0297726012 0.0083477640
2 2.0000000000 0.0101262961 0.1505082861 0.0672806552 18.0297726012 0.0083477640
2 3.0000000000 0.0074302504 0.1505082861 0.0493677164 18.0297726012 0.0083477640
2 4.0000000000 0.0057511342 0.1505082861 0.0382114125 18.0297726012 0.0083477640
2 6.0000000000 0.0053130805 0.1505082861 0.0353009170 18.0297726012 0.0083477640
2 7.0000000000 0.0056565361 0.1505082861 0.0375828883 18.0297726012 0.0083477640
2 8.0000000000 0.0083149576 0.1505082861 0.0552458459 18.0297726012 0.0083477640
3 1.0000000000 0.0326363429 0.0553721351 0.5894001165 18.0297726012 0.0030711499
3 3.0000000000 0.0037409247 0.0553721351 0.0675596971 18.0297726012 0.0030711499
3 6.0000000000 0.0013867221 0.0553721351 0.0250436808 18.0297726012 0.0030711499
3 8.0000000000 0.0097070545 0.0553721351 0.1753057659 18.0297726012 0.0030711499
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
tmp = df[['sector', 'radiotap.mcs.index']].groupby('sector').agg([max, min])
from itertools import product
rng = np.arange(0, tmp.loc[:,('radiotap.mcs.index', 'max')].max()+1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(tmp.index, rng)), columns=['sector','radiotap.mcs.index'])
df1 = df1.merge(df, on=['sector','radiotap.mcs.index'], how='outer')
df1.loc[:,['time_total_x_y', 'perc_sec_time']] = df1.loc[:,['time_total_x_y', 'perc_sec_time']].fillna(method='bfill')
df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df1
    sector  radiotap.mcs.index  time_total_x_x  time_total_y    perc_time   time_total_x_y  perc_sec_time
0   2   0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    18.029773   0.008348
1   2   1.0 0.107916    0.150508    0.717011    18.029773   0.008348
2   2   2.0 0.010126    0.150508    0.067281    18.029773   0.008348
3   2   3.0 0.007430    0.150508    0.049368    18.029773   0.008348
4   2   4.0 0.005751    0.150508    0.038211    18.029773   0.008348
5   2   5.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    18.029773   0.008348
6   2   6.0 0.005313    0.150508    0.035301    18.029773   0.008348
7   2   7.0 0.005657    0.150508    0.037583    18.029773   0.008348
8   2   8.0 0.008315    0.150508    0.055246    18.029773   0.008348
9   3   0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    18.029773   0.003071
10  3   1.0 0.032636    0.055372    0.589400    18.029773   0.003071
11  3   2.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    18.029773   0.003071
12  3   3.0 0.003741    0.055372    0.067560    18.029773   0.003071
13  3   4.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    18.029773   0.003071
14  3   5.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    18.029773   0.003071
15  3   6.0 0.001387    0.055372    0.025044    18.029773   0.003071
16  3   7.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    18.029773   0.003071
17  3   8.0 0.009707    0.055372    0.175306    18.029773   0.003071
```